# My XAML is not able to see my CustomClass

Tags: wpf, xaml

My class is called TileView

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace myApp
{
    public class TileView : ViewBase
```

My XAML looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="Camden_Automated_Help_Desk.ShortcutControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TileView x:Key="ImageDetailView">
```

For some reason I get an error saying **"TileView does not exist in the namespace clr-myApp"**

I am very confused about this because my TileView Class clearly is using the same namespace.

Comment: Are `ShortcutControl` and `TileView` in the same assembly? Does everything else compile?

Comment: Try adding the assembly name: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LeaderAnalytics.ForecastFramework.Components;assembly=LeaderAnalytics.ForecastFramework.Components"

Comment: It doesn't compile when I try to use TileView. Why will LeaderAnalytics help?

Comment: I just copy/pasted that from my code to show you an example of where to put assembly=. Assembly name should match the .dll name of the component.

Comment: I dont have a DLL component. My TileView class is a .cs class

Comment: is it in the same visual studio project as shortcutControl?

Comment: Yes it is in the same project